# angular 6 change closest icon when (click) is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a list that shows a caret icon on the left and it should change icon when it is clicked. Whenever I click on one icon all change icons.

```html
<div class="caret" *ngIf="summary.isSupervisor" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="openSubordinateInfo(i, summary)">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-right" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</div>
```

```javascript
detailedInfo = [];
subordinateInfo;

openSubordinateInfo(i, summary) {
  this.subordinateInfo = summary;

  if (this.detailedInfo[i]) {
    this.detailedInfo[i] = false;
    $(".caret i").toggleClass("zmdi-caret-down zmdi-caret-right");
  } else {
    this.detailedInfo[i] = true;
    $(".caret i").toggleClass("zmdi-caret-right zmdi-caret-down");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid resorting to jQuery in your Angular application. There will almost always be a solution using Angular.

In this case, you can change the icon directly in your HTML using `ngClass`.

```html
<div class="caret" *ngIf="summary.isSupervisor" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="openSubordinateInfo(i, summary)">
    <i class="zmdi" [ngClass]="{'zmdi-caret-down': detailedInfo[i], 'zmdi-caret-right': !detailedInfo[i]}" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</div>
```

This will conditionally apply the class based on the condition given.

Then your `openSubordinateInfo` function will look like this

```js
openSubordinateInfo(i, summary) {
    this.subordinateInfo = summary;
    this.detailedInfo[i] = !this.detailedInfo[i];
    // Add other logic here
}
```